# 32-bit Azure Functions Core Tools and Visual Studio

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

Can Visual Studio use the 32-bit version of Azure Functions Core Tools instead of the 64-bit version when debugging?  My Azure Function uses a third-party 32-bit DLL, so my code needs to run as 32-bit.  I need help finding a way to accomplish this using Visual Studio.  I can run my code at the command line without using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [**Blog**](https://devcodef1.com/news/1191999/debugging-32-bit-azure-functions-with-core-tools) to debug your Function project in Visual Studio with **32 bit Azure Functions Core tools.**

Also, Visual Studio will only pick the Azure Function core tools that's running at top in the control panel, *Thus you can uninstall `Azure Function 64 bit core tools` and keep `32 bit x86 Azure Function core tools` running.*

[image]

One more option is to set the Executable Path to Azure Function 32 bit core tools like below:-

***Right click on your Azure Function project > Debug > Executable > Path to Executable set to Azure function core tools 32 bit > command line arguments `host start`:-***

[image]

***You can select Toggle in Any CPU > Configuration Manager > and add New Platform set to x86***

[image]